# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in some cases

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, wget

Any idea why this program will fail in downloading images from page #12 while it did pages 1-9 perfectly? I really don't know how can I debug. Maybe there's a problem with wget when it doesn't find the first image? http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/7954/white2u.png

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for using system calls
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep

int main ()
{
    char  body[] = "forum-post-body-content", notes[] = "p-comment-notes", img[] = "img src=", link[200], cmd[200]={0}, file[10];
    int c, pos = 0, pos2 = 0, fin = 0, i, j, num = 0, found = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    for (i = 12; i <= 149; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(cmd,"wget -O page%d.txt 'http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/artwork/340782-official-digital-rendering-thread?page=%d'",i,i);
        system(cmd);
        sprintf(file, "page%d.txt", i);
        fp = fopen (file, "r");
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            if (body[pos] == c)
            {
                if (pos == 22)
                {
                    pos = 0;
                    while (fin == 0)
                    {
                        c = fgetc (fp);
                        if (feof (fp))
                            break;
                        if (notes[pos] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos == 14)
                            {
                                fin = 1;
                                pos = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos > 0)
                                pos = 0;
                        }
                        if (img[pos2] == c)
                        {
                            if (pos2 == 7)
                            {
                                pos2 = 0;
                                while (found == 0)
                                {
                                    c = fgetc (fp); // get char from file
                                    link[pos2] = c;
                                    if (pos2 > 0)
                                    {
                                        if(link[pos2-1] == 'g' && link[pos2] == '\"')
                                        {
                                        found = 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ++pos2;
                                }
                                --pos2;
                                found = 0;
                                char link2[pos2];
                                for (j = 1; j < pos2; ++j)
                                {
                                    link2[j - 1] = link[j];
                                }
                                link2[j - 1] = '\0';
                                sprintf(cmd, "wget -O /home/arturo/Dropbox/Digital_Renders/%d \'%s\'", ++num, link2);
                                system(cmd);
                                pos2 = -1;
                            }
                            ++pos2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(pos2 > 0)
                                pos2 = 0;
                        }
                    }
                fin = 0;
                }
                ++pos;
            }
            else
                pos = 0;
        }
        // closing file
        fclose (fp);
        if (remove (file))
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't remove file\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are starting with page 12 do you mean page 24?

Comment: No I changed the code to begin when it finds a problem quickly. In page 10 there's also the same problem but not with the first image.

Comment: so which line seg faults?

Comment: What was that 'image' link supposed to show? I get some advertising. (If it's a screen shot displaying textual output: please don't include that as an image to begin with.)

Comment: Have you run the program in a debugger?

Comment: There should be a .jpg image there but as there isn't one I think wget makes the program crash in line 69 `sprintf(cmd, "wget -O /home/arturo/Dropbox/Digital_Renders/%d \'%s\'", ++num, link2);` I'm still learning and don't know how to use the debugger yet.

Comment: You aren't checking if the fopen() works.  It will give a crashy NULL if it fails.

Comment: Yes I have reduced the code a little to show it here.

Comment: regarding this line: sprintf(file, "page%d.txt", i);  the char array 'file' is only 10 bytes long.  'page12.txt' is 11 bytes long (including the string terminator byte '\0'.  that '12' will go as high as '149' which will require 12 bytes to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char file[10];
```

`"page12.txt"` has 11 characters in it including the null character.  Please just do something like `char file[128]`.  Memory is cheap.  Time spent debugging is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You have an overflow.

file[10];

page1.txt  = 10 characters including the null terminator

page12.txt = 11 characters

Look into to the safe functions like snprintf()